# Symfony FOSUserBundle - Login - Invalid Credentials

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle, credentials

I am having issue with FosUserBundle,

Acctualy I followed this tutorial

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

And in the end it says You now can log in at "/app.com/app_dev.php/login!"

Here is [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArM34.jpg)

**My routing file:**

```
   app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation


# easy_admin_bundle:
    # resource: "@EasyAdminBundle/Controller/"
    # type:     annotation
    # prefix:   /admin

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

**My security file:**

```
    security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                # if you are using Symfony < 2.8, use the following config instead:
                # csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: how did you put your user into the database?

Comment: Manually throught database, because I couldn't do it using command promt, I don't know why :((       Here is a photo of console error I'm receiving when I try to insert a user http://postimg.org/image/b3l13wejh/

Comment: Acctualy I can not add password, when it comes to a add a password I can not write anymore in a console terminal, its fine with username, fine with email but when it says Please choose a password: I am not able to write anything ;(

Answer (score 2):

Manually putting the users details into the database is likely the issue.  Unless you go through the proper process you'll end up with an unencrypted password, so when you try to authenticate using bcrypt (as stated in your security file) the passwords wont match.

You have 2 options.  Command line or do it programatically.

---

**Command line creation**

Have a look at the [list of FOSUserBundle command line tools](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html).

Follow the [instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/command_line_tools.html#create-a-user) for creating a user and you should have more success. I know you tried this, but follow the tutorial and have another go.  Its worth trying to do this:

```
$ php bin/console fos:user:create adminuser --super-admin
```

and putting in the extra data as it asks you.

---

**Controller creation**

From a controller point of view, you need to use the `fos_user.user_manager` service to setup your new user.

So, something like this:

```
$userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->createUser();
```

then inside your form handling script:

```
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```

This will parse the `plainPassword` data gathered in and extracted from your form through the correct password encoder.  It'll then null the `plainPassword` property so remains secure in the database.

So, your finished controller method might look something like this:

```
public function newUser( Request $request ) {
    // get a blank user, you can use new User if you like but I like to use their tools seeing as they took the time to build them.
    $user = $this->get('fos_user.user.manager')->createUser();

    // build the form
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);

    // bind the form data (if there) to the entity.
    $form->handleRequest( $request );

    if ( $form->isSubmitted && $form->isValid() ) {
         // this will properly encode the password, if changed, remove any plain text versions and flush into the db.
         $this->get('fos_user.user.manager')->updateUser($user);

         // send the user somewhere with a congrats message
     } else {
         // anything for invalid form;
     }


    return $this->render('forms/form.html.twig', [
      'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User::**setPlainPassword()** method but not **setPassword()**